# Datatable ajax change result index

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I am using Datatables.js with ajax call.

My json response is :

```
"success":true,"message":"","items":[{"id":"1","ip_address":"127.0.0.1","email...
```

ie my data is in data.items. Can I set easily in datatable the index of data response ?

Comment: What do you mean?  In your columns definition you link the data to the columns.

Comment: I mean, how can I set the output to be data.items ? and not data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, have a look at https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax  and specifically:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "dataSrc": "tableData"
  }
} );
```

Comment: Yes ok it''s perfect. I didn"t see that :( Thanks !